# How to test AWS 'DynamoDB' table immediately after restore from Backup

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am writing python script to automate AWS DynamoDB table backup restore test. Once the table is restored from backup i can not check(test) table size or item count in restored table immediately. As per AWS "Storage size and item count are not updated in real-time. They are updated periodically, roughly every six hours."
I also tried using "scan" on the restored table to list sample items but that's also not seems to be working.

Does anybody know what could be the work around here? Suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by using, table scan.

```
client = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 'us-east-1')
table = client.Table('ddb_test_table')
    response = table.scan(Limit=XX)
```